# Enable scroll in div only when div is fully displayed

Tags: css, scroll

I have a `#header` (50 or 100vh height, no overflow) and a `#main` (100vh, overflowed contents). I know I can enable scrolling with `overflow:auto`; but I don't want that content to scroll separate from the window until the entirety of `#content` is displayed (aka `#header` is out of sight). Is this possible--short of inserting a click-button to auto-scroll out the header and keep it out of sight? (I've added the original answer below to this; can't tell what's preventing it from working.)

```js
$(function(){    
    let header = document.querySelector('#splash');
    let content = document.querySelector('#content');
    
    const overflowHandler = () => {
        if (window.scrollY >= header.offsetHeight) {
            content.style.overflow = 'auto';
        } else {
            content.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        }
    }    
    window.addEventListener('scroll', overflowHandler);
    
    // Sticky Nav
    var navbar = document.querySelector("#nav");
    var stick = navbar.offsetTop;
    window.onscroll = function stickyNavBar() {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= stick) {
            navbar.classList.add("sticky");
        } else {
            navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
    };
    
    // Scroll-to-Top
    var sbTopBtn = $('#nav').find("a#top")
    $('.autopagerize_page_element').scroll(function() {
        400 < $(this).scrollTop() ? sbTopBtn.addClass('active') : sbTopBtn.removeClass('active');
    });
    sbTopBtn.click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $('.autopagerize_page_element').animate({scrollTop: 0},600);
            $('body').animate({scrollTop: 0},600);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  text-align: center;
}

#splash {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #f00;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  z-index: 5;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #0f0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#prev, #next {
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.autopagerize_page_element {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="splash">
    contains 1 image and assorted text in two separate divs
    header height can be 50vh (current), 100vh, or user-defined<br>
    main panel and pagination buttons are 100vh; #content can scroll<br>
    sticky nav and scroll-to-top functions don't seem to work on this snippet 
    (latter currently won't scroll #content), but i left <br>them in just in 
    case they're contributing to the nonfunctionality of the proposed "all 
    elements scroll as unit" function.
  </section>

  <section id="nav">
    contains 5 FontAwesome icons. the center one is actually a div with a scroll-to-top function<br>
    <a id="top" href="#">demo scrolls abruptly</a>
  </section>

  <section id="content">
    <a id="prev" href="PREV"><</a>
    <div class="autopagerize_page_element"><article class="post" id="{PostID}">
      (autopagerize div left does infinite scroll with extra JS; it currently restricts
      #content's height to 100vh)<br>
      even if the cursor is over this div, this should scroll with the rest of the page
      page until head is offscreen. in other words, this div's scroll should not work 
      until the red is offscreen<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler
      <br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler
      <br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler
      <br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>pls don't look at me if red isn't offscreen
      <br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler
      <br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler
      <br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler
      <br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>end of content end of content end of content
    </article></div>
    <a id="next" href="NEXT">></a>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a javascript solution

```js
let header = document.querySelector('#header');
let content = document.querySelector('#main');

const overflowHandler = () => {
  if (window.scrollY >= header.offsetHeight) {
    content.style.overflow = 'auto';
  } else {
    content.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', overflowHandler);
```

```css
body {width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: auto}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background: #f00;
}

#main {
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    max-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #0f0;
}

.prev, .next {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    font-size: 4rem;
}

.prev {left: 0;}
.next {right: 0;}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
    header height can be 50vh, 100vh, or user-defined<br>
    pagination controls buttons are 100vh<br>
    main panel is 100vh with scrollable contents<br>
    (still figuring out how to make the whole pagination bar clickable, not just < a >)
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div class="prev"><a href="PREV"><</a></div>
    <div class="next"><a href="NEXT">></a></div>
    even if the cursor is over this div, this should scroll with the rest of the page
    page until head is offscreen. in other words, this div's scroll should not work 
    until the red is offscreen<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler
    <br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler
    <br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler
    <br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>pls don't look at me if red isn't offscreen<br>
    <br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler
    <br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler
    <br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>filler
    <br>filler<br>filler<br>filler<br>end of content end of content end of content
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does what I want, but possibly not perfectly. On this desktop, the reverse (scrolling #header back into view) doesn't seem to work unless I twitch my cursor again (anywhere within the window), but I don't know if that's just me or would actually be a problem in the long run. I was also hoping to recycle the basic layout for mobile displays too (hence the 100vh pagination buttons).

Comment: Hmm, upon insertion into my page (right before </body>, above all my other JS), it doesn't seem to work anymore. Maybe I shouldn't be pursuing this after all? Thanks, and sorry to waste your time.

Comment: it's okay, could you update your post with your current code ?

Comment: I've updated my snippet with a more complete-from-webpage code. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Do you import jquery in your project ?

Comment: A little bit, but I don't think it's causing the issue? I'm weakest in Javascript though. My site uses Jquery 1.8.3, "Style-My-Tooltips" (doesn't work with newer Jquery), "Modified Photosets" (makes Tumblr image posts display over a lightbox instead of redirecting the page), and what should be an irrelevant Infinite Scroll script since I added it after this post was made. Full site is ninthms-test.tumblr.com if you want to take a look.